# Merge consecutive duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to de-duplicate some data in an SQL Server table and I can't find a solution so i'm hoping someone can help. I've searched for answers and most seem to say this is an "Islands and Gaps" problem but I can't adjust the solutions I've seen to fit my scenario.

Here is an example of the source data I'm working with

[image: Source Example[1]]

Where the price is the same on consecutive rows I'd like to merge those into a single row with the overall valid from and to date.

[image: Target[2]]

I've tried using the `PARTITION OVER` clause but that always seems to group all of the same prices together even if there is another price in between and seems to ignore the `ORDER BY` part of the partition.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the questions in the tag I've added, there are 100's of examples on how to do this. Unless this is just a simple `MIN` and `MAX`.

Comment: Are we to assume ValidFrom defines the order by which we can decide on previous and that the ValidFrom/ValidTo periods do not overlap?

Comment: Yes it can be ordered by ValidFrom and the periods won't overlap

Comment: What if there are gaps in the data?  For instance, if the second row ended in 2015 rather than 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`s & find the groups to do aggregation  :

```
select item, price, min(validfrom) as validfrm, max(validto) as valdto
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over(partition by item order by validfrom desc) as seq1,
             row_number() over(partition by item, price order by validfrom desc) as seq2
      from table t
     ) t
group by item, price, (seq1 - seq2)
order by item, validfrm desc;
```